# Нужна помощь с созданием градиентного фона

Tags: android, xml

Всем привет! Пожалуйста, помогите создать градиентный фон. Суть такова: фон имеет цвет `#D0D0D0`. Сверху вниз идёт градиент шириной `20dp` с `#000000` до `#D0D0D0`. И точно также снизу вверх идёт градиент той же ширины с `#000000` до `#D0D0D0`. Если непонятно, то я хочу сделать так, как [здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYsfV.png), только со своими цветами. Уже несколько часов мучаюсь с этими `layer-list`, `stroke` и т.д. - никак не могу сообразить!

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Можно попробовать 2 градиента сделать